# Shopware 5.6 Update Attribute model is broken

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, shopware

I've updated a shopware Project from 5.5 to 5.6.8.
In Result the generated Doctrine Model for the attribute table 's_articles_attributes' is broken.

At the end of the class it generates these two function

```
public function get()
{
    return $this->;
}

public function set($)
{
    $this-> = $;
    return $this;
}
```

Which results in the following error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting identifier
> (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in
> var/cache/production/doctrine/attributes/Article.php
> on line 699

My *PHP Version* is *7.2.33*

As *Database* I use *MariaDB 10.3.33*

Comment: Running the [repair foreign keys script](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-5-en/tutorials-and-faq/repair-foreign-keys), as recommanded [here](https://forum.shopware.com/discussion/55159/bitte-um-hife-fehlermedung-php-message-php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected), doesn't solves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some Reason the PHP-File which normaly contains the class Shopware\Models\Article\Detail was empty, so the generator couldn't build the correct asssociation.
After redownloading the sources everything went well.